# Can the image of chains on a smooth manifold be thought of as a Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, differential-geometry

Volume forms on smooth manifolds have a nice interpretation as measures, but what takes the place of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra? In particular, if we let $\mathcal{M}$ be a smooth manifold and $\mathcal{B} ( \mathcal{M} )$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open neighborhoods of the manifold, then is $\mathcal{B} ( \mathcal{M} )$ equivalent to the image of top-rank chains on $\mathcal{M}$?

Naively $\mathcal{B} (\mathcal{M} )$ is well-defined, in particular countable additivity should come from the local charts, but I'm struggling to find a more geometric interpretation and I haven't been able to find a readable reference on chains that gets into the details like countable additivity.  Pedagogical references welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a world of difference between measurable sets and chains! Just because some people choose to write the operations in a $\sigma$-algebra using $+$ and $-$ and so on doesn't mean it's an abelian group under those operations!

Comment: The $\sigma$-algebra is the domain of measures, chains the domains of volume forms.  Ignoring the additional group structure of the chains and associating measures with forms there should be some equivalence of the objects as sets, no?  In particular I'm just interested in chains serving as a $\sigma$-algebra, not the other way around.

Comment: No. Chains are things you _integrate_ over, and for a start, they are _not_ subsets of the manifold.

Comment: Everything I've seen defines chains as compositions of images of simplices mapped onto the manifold, which be a subset of the manifold, no?  Can you recommend a pedagogical reference if I'm completely off base here?

Comment: That is not the correct definition. An $n$-chain in a manifold $M$ is a formal sum (with integer or real coefficients, according to taste) of finitely many smooth maps $\Delta^n \to M$.

Comment: Okay, excuse my imprecise language.  The image of those maps (is it fine to say the image of the chain?) is a union of subsets of the manifold, no?

Comment: I can cover an element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{M})$ in charts, map to a corresponding element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, and then compute the measure as usual locally.  I'm after as much geometric perspective as I can about this process -- if chains are too restrictive I understand, I just can't convince myself one way or the other.

Comment: You can consider the image if you like. But then you are not talking about chains anymore.